# Как задать flex-basis между блоками?

Tags: css, css3, flexbox

[image: Блоки]

Выполняю верстку по Perfect Pixel. Как мне правильно задать flex-basis calc для того, чтобы расположить блоки правильно. На картинке относительное растояние установленное justify-content: space-between;

Comment: не совсем понимаю что вы хотите сделать.... что сейчас не так?

Comment: Что значит расположить блоки правильно? Покажите как нибудь как выглядит это "правильно".

Comment: С отступами между блоками 30px. Там значительно меньше

Comment: @FrencOlesov Для начала когда отвечайте в комментариях используйте знак "@" а то мне не видно. Во вторых justify-content: space-between; даёт значение автоматически и чтобы его изменить используйте margin. Ну например вам надо 30px тогда дайте margin: 0px 15px; этим блокам

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`justify-content: space-between`; уровняет расстояние внутри блоков.
Если вам не нравится расстояние вы всегда можете его изменить с помощью `margin`

[image]

Как я понял вы хотите чтобы расстояние около блоков был столько, сколько внутри. Для этого вам подойдёт `justify-content: space-around` или `justify-content:space-evenly`
Понять какое вам лучше подойдёт поможет [этот](https://webref.ru/css/justify-content) сайт

[image]
[image]